# how to create bamboo jobs equivalent to jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, bamboo

I have some jenkins pipelines and I want to create the equivalent job in bamboo.
Can anybody suggest me the procedure?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post related to the same:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/importing-data-from-jenkins-317949257.html